# How does hyphen, en-dash and em-dash gets stored in oracle database having character set WEISO98859P1?

Tags: java, oracle, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a java web application which uses oracle database. Character set of my database is WEISO98859P1. The problem which i am facing is, The characters like en-dash and em-dash gets stored inverted ? or some other weird symbol. Same goes while retrieving and displaying the data.

What can be the workaround for this problem?

Comment: This table shows all the characters that are part of the ISO 8859-1 character set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1  Do the characters you are having problems with appear there?  If so, which character are they?  It sounds like you want to store a character that doesn't exist in the database character set.

Comment: Are you sure they are STORED inverted? Use `dump()` to see what numeric value is STORED for each character and compare to the character map (use the link Justin has provided). That will help tell whether the problem is what is being stored vs. what is being DISPLAYED - these are two different issues with different solutions.

Comment: I am trying to store either of the followings: hyphen (-), en dash (–), and em dash (—) Seems like en dash and em dash are not supported by the character set.

Comment: Mentioned characters are not supported by character set `WEISO98859P1`. So, there is no workaround. If you like to use such characters you have to migrate your database to a character set which supports them, e.g. `AL32UTF8`. The only "workaround" is to use `NVARCHAR2` data types, in most cases these are set to some Unicode character set.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store “en-dash” (–) and “em-dash” (—) in an Oracle database with character set WE8ISO8859P1, since these characters are not defined in that character set.

The best thing would be to convert the database to character set WE8MSWIN1252. You can do that without changing any of the data in the database, since WE8MSWIN1252 is a superset of WE8ISO8859P1. WE8MSWIN1252 contains “en-dash” (code point 96) and “em-dash” (code point 97).